# O que é e para que serve a estrutura sockaddr_in?

Tags: c++, socket, struct

Ultimamente andei querendo programar uns soquetes de rede em C++ porém como os matérias na internet sobre isso são um pouco limitados chegando a mostrar somente como programar os soquetes sem explicar mais detalhadamente o uso de cada função eu acabei me perdendo um pouco e umas das coisas que mais me deixou em dúvida foi o uso da estrutura "sockaddr_in". Portanto, o que é e para que serve a estrutura sockaddr_in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em suma é essa estrutura que lida com os endereços de rede.

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;
    unsigned short   sin_port;
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;
    char             sin_zero[8];
};
```

Essa em particular é a estrutura usada com endereços **IPv4**, por exemplo 192.168.123.123.

Além dessa estrutura existem diversas outras estruturas básicas para todos os sistemas e funções que lidam com os endereços da internet. Muitas vezes você usará [`getaddrinfo ()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) para preencher essas estruturas e depois as lê quando for necessário.

Comment: "Essa em particular é a estrutura usada com endereços IPv4..." - Qual seria a estrutura para trabalhar com IPV6?

Comment: @Khyser A estrutura para **IPv6** é a `struct sockadd_in6`